# do fetching links for files in firebase cost us like download operations android Java

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

In my android application, I have 300 files in firebase cloud storage (not firestore). There are two things, like fetching a link and then we use it to download. In firebase pricing

[image]

As you can see above, the cost is for downloading and uploading operations only. But now I am confused when I fetch a link from firebase will it be counted as a download operation or not. Here is some code to fetch a link.

```
storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        // Got the download URL 
        // will this counter as a operation
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

The actual code for downloading file looks like

```
 void startDownloading(final String DownloadUrl, String DownloadPath, String DownloadName) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            final File file = new File(StringManager.phoneStorageLocation + "/"
                    + DownloadPath + "/" + DownloadName);
            
            try {
                URL url = new URL(DownloadUrl);
                ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
                fos.close();
                rbc.close();

            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }
```

Above is the code where I actually use the link to download the file. And here definitely or obviously it will be counted as a download operation.

So again my question is that, will fetching a link be counted as a download operation? and will fetching metadata will count as an operation that costs us money. Summary - Operations other than upload or download (like metadata, links, getting names of files, etc. ), if we use them will they cost us money or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> will fetching a link be counted as a download operation?

No.

> and will fetching metadata will count as an operation that costs us money

According to the [pricing overview for Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#pricing), retrieving object metadata is a class B operation, which is $0.004 per 10,000 operations.

Comment: So firebase cloud and google cloud storage are the same. I thought that they were different. So fetching 10,000 links will cost me 0.004$. Am I right?

Comment: "Firebase cloud" isn't really a thing.  Firebase provides SDKs for some Google Cloud products to use in web and mobile apps, and the billing is the same for everything.  The documentation is correct.

Comment: Ok got it, let me confirm that fetching links is not free of cost. As it is metadata, please let me know am I right

Comment: I don't see anything in documentation that suggests getting a download URL costs anything.  If you have billing questions that are not covered in the documentation, you should reach out to Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson If I retrieve 500 video download URLs from Firebase storage, I will be charged. However, if I store all of these links locally using shared preferences, and then fetch them again in the future from the shared preferences, will I be charged again?